# Find the latitude and longitude using javascript

Tags: javascript, latitude-longitude

I am using javascript for the first time.Actually i want to get the latitude and longitude of an address using java script.Can anyone guide me..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need latitude and longitude of a given adress, you can use google maps api
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Here is an example: 
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

EDIT: to display it in an alert popup:

```
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  var location = results[0].geometry.location;
  alert(location.lat() + '' + location.lng());
});
```

Comment: The question says "of an address" not "of the user's location".

Comment: this would find the lat/lng of the client connected, it won't find the position of an address - and w3schools reference should be avoided (see w3fools.com)

Comment: sorry, I've updated my answer to correctly answer the question

Comment: i just want the latitude and longitude in an alert box

Comment: Hey Jerome, in Firefox (and perhaps all browsers), your alert( ) is actually adding the latitude and longitude as if they were floating point numbers, then displaying the results.  One easy fix is to use: alert(location.lat() + ' ' + location.lng());  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the JS+HTML code(based on answer from Jerome C.):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Geocoding service</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        function codeAddress() {
        var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          var location = results[0].geometry.location;
          alert('LAT: ' + location.lat() + ' LANG: ' + location.lng());
        });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', codeAddress);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Tembhurkheda, Maharashtra, INDIA">
      <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

using [Google maps api v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/) you could study the source code of this example:
http://universimmedia.pagesperso-orange.fr/geo/loc.htm